# Functional way of creating a vector of vector of &str in Rust where the separator will be an empty new line

Tags: rust

I am doing the advent of code 2022 day 11, where I have the following input as a &str:

```
Monkey 0:
    Starting items: 52, 60, 85, 69, 75, 75
    Operation: new = old * 17
    Test: divisible by 13
      If true: throw to monkey 6
      If false: throw to monkey 7
  
  Monkey 1:
    Starting items: 96, 82, 61, 99, 82, 84, 85
    Operation: new = old + 8
    Test: divisible by 7
      If true: throw to monkey 0
      If false: throw to monkey 7
  
  Monkey 2:
    Starting items: 95, 79
    Operation: new = old + 6
    Test: divisible by 19
      If true: throw to monkey 5
      If false: throw to monkey 3
```

how can I use the functional api of rust to get a vector of vector where the inner vector would contain the phrases of a monkey block? The separator should be the empty new line.
The output should be something like this:

```
[["Monkey 0:", "    Starting items: 52, 60, 85, 69, 75, 75", "    Operation: new = old * 17", "    Test: divisible by 13", "      If true: throw to monkey 6", "      If false: throw to monkey 7"], ["  Monkey 1:", "    Starting items: 96, 82, 61, 99, 82, 84, 85", "    Operation: new = old + 8", "    Test: divisible by 7", "      If true: throw to monkey 0", "      If false: throw to monkey 7"]]
```

I have managed to do it in the imperative way, but I was not able to create it using the functional way (map, filter, fold, etc). I think the functional way is way more idiomatic rust

Comment: Where is the problem? Just use `split`, `map` and `collect` as appropriate. Where did your attempt fail? We can't judge cause you forgot to append it.

Comment: You will most likely want to use [`str::split_prefix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.strip_prefix) to handle parsing out the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split

```rust
let sections: Vec<Vec<&str>> = inpu
    .split("\n\n")
    .map(|section| -> Vec<&str> { section.lines().collect() })
    .collect();
```

Comment: That got me:


[["Monkey 0:", "    Starting items: 52, 60, 85, 69, 75, 75", "    Operation: new = old * 17", "    Test: divisible by 13", "      If true: throw to monkey 6", "      If false: throw to monkey 7", "  ", "  Monkey 1:", "    Starting items: 96, 82, 61, 99, 82, 84, 85", "    Operation: new = old + 8", "    Test: divisible by 7", "      If true: throw to monkey 0", "      If false: throw to monkey 7", "  ", "  Monkey 2:", "    Starting items: 95, 79", "    Operation: new = old + 6", "    Test: divisible by 19", "      If true: throw to monkey 5", ...]]

Comment: Not quite what I need

Comment: Guessing you are on windows. Sometimes when you copy text in windows it changes the line-endings from `\n` to `\r\n`. You might try `.split("\r\n\r\n")` instead.

Alternatively, if you want your program to work with both kinds of line ending, checkout the [group_by](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by) function from itertools.